# Unexpected Safari page load count behavior

Tags: php, apache, safari

### Client

- Mac OS 10.15.3

### Server

- Ubuntu 18.04.4
- Apache 2.4.29
- PHP 7.4.5

Take a script, call it /test.php.  Let's track how many *actual* page loads happen per visual, user-experienced page load.

```
# Count = 1
test.php?v=1
# Count = 2
test.php?v=1
# Count = 4 (???)
test.php?v=2
# Count = 7 (???)
test.php?v=1
# Count = 8 
test.php?v=1
# Count = 10 (???)
test.php?v=3
# Count = 11
test.php?v=3
# Count = 15 (???)
test.php?v=2
# Count = 18 (???)
test.php?v=1
```

In Chrome, the number of loads is as expected - 1, 2, 3, then 4, 5, etc.

Furthermore, Safari behaves as expected - as Chrome behaves - if you do this in a Private Window.

Why is Safari behaving like this?  Is there contribution from something else in the stack, such as from Apache or PHP?

### EDIT 1

Apache log of a smaller test case.  **(!!!)** test.php?v=3 is logged despite not willfully being requested by me.

```
# Procedure
test.php?v=1
test.php?v=1
test.php?v=2
```

```
# Apache Log of above page loads with IP redacted.
REDACTED_IP - - [20/Apr/2020:11:35:26 +0000] "GET /test.php?v=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 8875 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
REDACTED_IP - - [20/Apr/2020:11:35:28 +0000] "GET /test.php?v=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 5141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
REDACTED_IP - - [20/Apr/2020:11:35:42 +0000] "GET /test.php?v=3 HTTP/1.1" 200 8876 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
REDACTED_IP - - [20/Apr/2020:11:35:42 +0000] "GET /test.php?v=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 5141 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
REDACTED_IP - - [20/Apr/2020:11:35:43 +0000] "GET /test.php?v=2 HTTP/1.1" 200 5705 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
```

### Edit 2

Here are the stripped-down contents of test.php.  Requires Redis and PHP-Redis, as I'm using that for a quick visual.  You can of course use Apache logs instead if you wish, or any other way to quickly see the number of times the script has been executed.

```
<?php 
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

echo $redis->incr('counter');
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. What is `test.php` doing? Have you looked at your Apache logs to see exactly how many page loads there really are? Have you watched the Network developer tab in your browser to see if anything weird is happening there?

Comment: test.php is a blank page with some MySQL and Redis logging to make sure I wasn't going insane.  You can see from the Apache log example I put in my edit (thanks for suggesting that clarification) that Safari even calls test.php?v=3, which I had previously visited, although not in that sequence.

Comment: I suspect this is due to some optimization for Safari to speed up future loads, due to it not occurring in private mode.  

Even more reason to respect the meaning of HTTP verbs?  Since this implies truly undesirable behavior could occur if someone puts non GET functionality in a GET path.